# Data visualization techniques for presenting text mining results

Tags: nlp, data-visualization, text-mining

I'm using text mining to explore differences in term use across speech domains in a natural language corpus. The research will primarily look at the distribution of key terms. What are some appropriate and effective ways of visually presenting this sort of information?

Answer (score 1):

Many text mining methods center around frequencies of single, double and triple word pairs - especially if you're doing exploratory data analysis. So you can rely on bar/column charts, histograms. Word clouds can be useful if not too dense, not too many grams.

If you ware talking about ML results, then you'll likely rely less on visualizations and more about predictions and coefficients.

I just did some exploratory text analysis for my Coursera class:
http://rpubs.com/polyoptik/coursera-capstone-milestone-report

I'd be happy to discuss further, I find this work exciting.